# Clarity on J-1 visa language

Tags: visa, students

I got my J-1 visa renewed yesterday at the US consulate in India. The visa and DS-2019 say "Bearer is NOT subject to section 212 (e)" and "Not subject to the two-year residency requirement", respectively. But on the visa, it also says "two-year rule does apply". My previous J-1 visa had said, "two-year rule does NOT apply". I believe this is a typo. Please let me know if it is and in that case what would I need to do. I have to fly back over the weekend and will not be able to get in touch with the embassy till I reach the US.

Comment: By the way: The site https://travel.stackexchange.com has a couple people who are very knowledgeable in visa regulations. You might get an even better answer there.

Comment: @Philipp this question is off topic for [Travel.SE] because it concerns a long-term stay.  [Expatriates.SE] is a better fit.

Comment: Why do you think it's a typo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whether a specific visa has a typo is not a question about the law and may involve legal advice as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not write the word *visa* in all caps.  It is not an acronym.  It is not a trademark (when used in this sense).  It is just a word.

The annotations all mean the same thing.  There is no typo.

> Bearer is NOT subject to section 212 (e)

This means that you are not subject to the two year residency requirement created by INA section 212(e).

> Not subject to the two-year resident requirement

This means that you are not subject to the two year residency requirement created by INA section 212(e).

> two year rule does NOT apply

This means that you are not subject to the two year residency requirement created by INA section 212(e).

Comment: Thanks. But the last sentence says "two year rule DOES apply" instead of "two year rule DOES NOT apply". Hence, the confusion.

Comment: @j1_student then I suggest you edit the question to reflect that.  Let me know when you've done so so I can change the answer.